# How do I get a Vodafone K3772-Z USB modem working?

Tags: usb-modem

I recently switched from Win 7 to Ubuntu 12.04...Best day of my life :)

I have a question relating to my Vodafone K3772-Z USB modem. When I plug it in, the lights start flashing on the device, meaning that it is functional. In the network menu I get a "Wired network Vodafone K3772-Z disconnected". I have set up the a connection by using Edit connections -> mobile broadband -> Add, but in the add window the "Create a connection for this mobile device" is blanked out and says "Any Device".

Does anyone perhaps have an idea of what I could do to get it working?

Comment: I am using a dual boot running Xp sp2 with Kubuntu 12.04 Could any one please point me into the right direction? Could I use the same way of fixing this or do have to use another way?

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I have kind of an answer. This might help some of the other South Africans out there that are struggling with 3G connections on Ubuntu 12.04. If I go to the terminal and type `gksudo gnome-ppp` (of course gnome-ppp must be installed, but you can also use wvdial) and click on Setup and then on Detect, it detects the Vodafone USB modem (it also works with my other 3G device, a Huawei E1690 USB stick).

At init strings, I make `Init2 = "ATZ"` and `Init3="ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"`.
As for the rest of the settings I use:

```
Number: `*99***1#`
Username: user
Password: pass
```

This connects to the Internet seamlessly, but it does take a little while to get connected.

As for the Network Manager, I still can't seem to get the connection available in the menu.

Hope it helps you, if anyone out there knows how to get my connection in the network manager menu please let me know. :)

Answer (score 2):

TO detail the above for vodafone data card K3372, Create a file name by using terminal (or CRTL+ALT+T) and type `sudo gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1526` now add the following code:

```
TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x14bc
MessageContent="55534243123456780002000080000a11062000000000000100000000000000"
```

and save the file.

Now in the terminal type the following:

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

Copy the line that contains "12d1" and "1520" (or any other line), paste/insert it somewhere else and change the second value from "1520" to "1526".

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

This is for new vodafone data card, model K3772. I had the problem of getting detected, Follow these steps, it really worked for me (not tested with model no:k3772-Z as my model is K3772):

Create a file named 12d1:1526 in the folder `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d`.

Edit it and fill it with this text:

Code:

```
TargetVendor=  0x12d1  
TargetProduct= 0x14bc



MessageContent="55534243123456780002000080000a11062000000000000100000000000000"
```

Now edit `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`. Copy the line that contains 12d1 and 1520 (or any other line), paste/insert it somewhere else and change the second value from 1520 to 1526.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SAKIS3G](http://www.sakis3g.org/) to form a connection without unlocking it. I never unlocked the device and it worked fine. 
NOTE: I could also use another network's sim on a network locked device using SAKIS3G.

Answer (score 0):

Just bought a Vodafone K3772-Z USB modem. Could not get it to work at all in 12.04 but, I have dual boot Windows 7 and 12.04.

Boot into Windows 7 and allow the Vodafone K3772-Z USB modem to register, install and check that its working. Then reboot back into Ubuntu.

Click on **Network Manager** indicator → **Edit Connections** → **Mobile Broadband** tab → **add the new Vodafone connection**.

It worked the first time without any issues. Why, I don't know. But, there must be something in Windows which has to activate the device first.

Hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to unlock the card is from Windows:

1. Connect to your vendor from Windows (unlock the stick)
2. Reboot and boot from Ubuntu (do not unplug the usb stick)
3. Connect from Ubuntu

This procedure must be repeated every time you need to use the stick from Ubuntu.

Hope an easier solution will be occur soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is for new vodafone data card, model K3772. I had the problem of getting detected, Follow these steps, it really worked for me (not tested with model no:k3772-Z as my model is K3772):

Create a file named `12d1:1526` in the folder `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d`.

Edit it and fill it with this text:

```
Code:  
TargetVendor=  0x12d1  
TargetProduct= 0x14bc  

MessageContent="55534243123456780002000080000a11062000000000000100000000000000"
```

Now edit `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`. Copy the line that contains `12d1` and `1520` (or any other line), paste/insert it somewhere else and change the second value from `1520` to `1526`.

That's it.